# Attachable Piano Stand

Tags: piano, keyboard, stand

I have a Yamaha P45 keyboard and it has screw holes at the bottom.  But I can't seem to find a piano stand that will attach to it.  The Yamaha L3C doesn't specify my type of piano and I don't think it would be strong enough.  Why would Yamaha put screw holes if they can't be used?

Are the Z type stands easy to knock the keyboard off? I can't find a Z type stand that's attachable to a keyboard. The 20 inch depth would seem to hold a keyboard on a little better than a 16 inch.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the time, a piano as light as this would just be put onto an X-stand. I only use X-stands for the lightest of keyboards - and never for gigging! A Z-stand will do fine instead, or one with four legs is even better. But for home use an X-stand will be plenty good enough. The screw holes are probably for fixing it to the $100 wooden stand made by Yamaha for it. (A quick Google provided this).

Even on gigs, keyboards  are not usually attached to their stands. If you're in a situation where it's likely to get knocked off, then even attached, it's not a good situation to have it in! Velcro between keyboard and stand might be an answer.

Comment: Thanks Tim. I appreciate the comments.  I will go ahead and get a Z type stand and not be concerned with attaching it to the piano. They seems to offer a little more room for legs.  They appear to me to be a little more stable but I have no experience with them as I am a beginner.  I use it only at home.